# Emoji from tweets not displaying properly under blog's "Recent Tweets" section

Tags: bug, blog

The title says it all, but perhaps an image says it better. The blog doesn't display this tweet properly:

Chrome on macOS High Sierra (edit: it's now fixed on this system):

> [image]

Safari iOS (edit: still not fixed here):

> [image]

While there's no formatting problem in the [actual tweet](https://twitter.com/juliasilge/status/1067449149073674240) (on either):

> [image]

What's happening is that the emoji you see in the macOS  screenshot are actually the alt text for an image that isn't displaying (does it have a proper URL, actually?):

```
<img draggable="false" class="emoji" alt="‍" src="&lt;a href='https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/11/svg/1f469' target='blank'&gt;https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/11/svg/1f469&lt;/a&gt;-1f3fe-200d-1f3eb.svg">
```

It's failing with several similar errors such as:

> Unsafe attempt to load URL https://zgab33vy595fw5zq-zippykid.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/stackoverflow/assets/svg/output/symbol-defs.svg from frame with URL https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/05/19/new-automatic-account-association/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

I don’t know what’s happening on iOS that not even the alt text is working. I do have the right emoji on my system: ‍‍...

You can probably see this behavior on almost any page on the Stack Overflow Blog, but I saw it [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/05/19/new-automatic-account-association/).

Comment: Twitter uses their own emoji, [Twemoji](https://emojipedia.org/twitter/) while the alt-text is the unicode character of the Emoji. That said, [no repro on Chrome 70 (no extension), macOS Mojave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlbKa.png)

Comment: Could repro here, Chrome 70 @ Win10(x64). The **`src`** of each emoji image has a strange value such as `<a href='https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/11/svg/1f469' target='blank'>https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/11/svg/1f469</a>-1f3fe-200d-1f3eb.svg`, or in short: a full `<a href=... target=... ></a>` tag + some text is used as the **`src`**. Not sure if the src is relevant, could also be the [`&zwj;` (zero-width-joiner)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner) in the alt text.

Comment: **Slightly Off-topic:** I'm not against emojis (I just don't use them much) but what purpose do they serve in that Tweet?

Comment: @Script47 It drives attention to the tweet - basic "millennial" marketing.

Comment: @Script47 Presumably to score progressiveness points. I think the intended message is "Look at us! We even work with women and dark people!". This is pretty normal in modern corporate messaging, of course.

Comment: @MarkAmery and people fall for this stuff? Honestly, overly using emojis just makes me glance across your message.

Comment: I agree with @PeterB, adornments to Emojis are not always followed. Emojis, may not be directly rendered, but rather replaced by images, which do not follow adornments.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter is replacing the emojis with images. Stack Overflow is attempting to do the same, but there is a 404 error on the svg files.  The unsafe load attempt is a checkerboard pattern(not related to the issue.)

The image requests from s.w.org are improperly formatted.(Appears to be internally redirected improperly, or an external reference applied as a reference address).

The alternate Emojis render with "spaces(broken images)" and monochrome characters, because that is how your browser/system interprets them.

**Edit** first time emojis on mobile work worse than desktop.

Comment: Strangely enough, I literally just edited my question 10 minutes ago to add how it looks on iOS. It's broken there too and doesn't even show the alt text that I see on my Mac.

Comment: It seems both Android and IOS fail when rendering.  IOS wanting images and Android(5) giving a response similar to the Chrome above.